# Entity Framework relations and AutoDetectChanges=false issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework

My goal is to have massive insert/update operation implemented.
The domain model consists of **Image** entity related to **Folder** entity as many-to-one.

Normally I add an image to the db context this way:

```
var folder = dbContext.Folders.First();

var image = new Image();
image.Folder = folder;
image.<SomeFields> = "<SomeData>";

dbContext.Images.Add(image);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

In order to have better performance I turn off automatic changes tracking:

```
dbContext.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
```

And now I get an error:

> Entities in 'DbContext.Images' participate in the 'Image_Folder'
>   relationship. 0 related 'Image_Folder_Target' were found. 1
>   'Image_Folder_Target' is expected.

I tried to use:

```
folder.Images.Add(image);
dbContext.Entry(folder).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

but it didn't help.

How should I fix an error?

UPD: fixed code snippet

UPD2: Simplified entities (removed inheritance from the base class (to make the code more readable) and most of needless attributes):

*Image.cs*

```
public class Image
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string AuthorName { get; set; }

    public string AuthorUrl { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR")]
    public new string File { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool IsCover { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Order { get; set; }

    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual Folder Folder { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return File;
    }

    public Image()
    {
        Order = 1;
    }
}
```

*Folder.cs*

```
public class Folder
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Folder Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Image> Images { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Folder> Folders { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }

    public Folder()
    {
        Images = new HashSet<Image>();
    }
}
```

Comment: I test your code, no exception occur, but no data entered into database

Answer (score 1):

I test your code, no exception occur, but no data inserted into database. Try this, replace **** code

```
dbContext.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
var folder = dbContext.Folders.First();

var image = new Image();
image.Folder = folder;
image.<SomeFields> = "<SomeData>";

**dbContext.Entry(image).State = EntityState.Added; **

dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I edited an answer - I missed additing to the dbcontext part.
As you can see, I add the object to the context and then, after saving changes, an exception occurs

Comment: if without set AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false, all things is ok, plz add entity models to questions, if not problem is other things

Comment: I test your code in Console App, all things is Ok, you can get test file in this link https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxQDI1Ct3mDRTW1YdVF6TnlZdHc

Comment: plz test in seperate project for detect bug,

Comment: I've read the code, it looks just like in my application. It looks like you're right about having some other reasons for an exception to occur. Unfortunately

Comment: Do you have a test when automatic changes tracking is enabled or in seperate project?

Comment: will test it thoroughly a bit later, thanks in advice